# Legend properties window is incomplete in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend, arcgis-10.8

The Legend properties window in ArcMap 10.8 doesn't display all properties.

[image: il looks like something wrong with display properties]

Comment: Is this the only windows that show this behavior? Or can you test with some others as well? Like Layer properties, Data Frame properties etc....

Comment: Yes, only these windows show this behavior.

Comment: Did you try resetting the application user profile? Try renaming the ESRI folders in Local and Roaming profile in C-->Users-->Profile-->AppData-->Local-->ESRI(Rename), and ---> Roaming --> ESRI(Rename).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by monitor resolution settings. These two Esri support articles provide explanation and fixes.

- [FAQ: Why does the ArcMap interface appear blurry when the screen resolution is changed to a resolution other than 96 dpi?](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012643)
- [Problem: Cannot see or select 'Save as type' on ArcMap Export Map dialog box](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007346)

Comment: I tried this solution with many other options, doesn't work.